# Can Hive do Spark-like flatmap/map operations?

Tags: sql, hive

Over the past few months, I've been using Spark to do my data clean stuff. For most cases, it's just filtering or some simple aggregation.

Recently, I found that large portion of the tasks can be done in Hive using HQL. But I found that it's difficult to do `map`, especially `flatmap` using Hive.

In a sense, `select` -like operations are `map` operations, but what if `flatmap` ?

Can someone give some tips ?

Thanks.

Comment: [`LATERAL VIEW`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a limited way lateral view (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView) can do a flatmap.